# Python XML-парсер выдает исключение на символе &#30;

Tags: python, xml, soap

Мне нужно парсить на питоне XML-ответы от сервера. Для парсинга использую библиотеку untangle. Почти все ответы парсятся без ошибок, но иногда парсер падает из-за того, что в XML есть какие-то странные символы. В логах я увидел, что парсер упал на позиции 97:48, где стоит символ `&#30;`. Что делать, когда в XML попадаются такие символы? Как их обрабатывать, чтобы парсер не падал?

Воспроизведенная ошибка:

`test`:

```
<reply><invNotification value="Àëåêñåé Ìèõàéëîâè÷ Áåö Ò&#30;:8-9068237378"/></reply>
```

`test.py`

```
import untangle

obj = untangle.parse("test")
```

`Ошибка:`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    obj = untangle.parse("test")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/untangle.py", line 177, in parse
    parser.parse(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 110, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 217, in feed
    self._err_handler.fatalError(exc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/handler.py", line 38, in fatalError
    raise exception
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: test:1:55: reference to invalid character number
```

Comment: Приведите чуть более полный кусок вашего XML

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести небольшой xml документ, на котором воспроизводится данная проблема?

Comment: @vp_arth, обновил пост.

Comment: Ну вообще это абсолютно корректный xml, который отлично парсится библиотекой lxml, возможно какая-то проблема в самом untangle

Comment: Вы понимаете, что такое "небольшой"? Я имел в виду "минимальный"

Comment: Например, воспроизводится ли ошибка в `<reply><invNotification value="Àëåêñåé Ìèõàéëîâè÷ Áåö Ò&#30;:8-9068237378"/></reply>`?

Comment: @vp_arth, воспроизводится. Обновил пост.

Comment: Вот теперь хорошо, спасибо.